# Does variable assignment at command line need to follow -v for gawk?

Tags: awk, gawk

From The Awk Programming Language

> ```
> awk  [ -Fs]  'program'  optional list of filenames 
> awk  [ -Fs]  -f progfile  optional list of filenames
> ```
>
> The option  -Fs sets  the  field  separator variable  FS  to  s.  If
>   there  are  no  filenames,  the  standard  input  is  read.  **A 
>   filename  can  be  of  the  form  var=text,  in  which  case  it  is 
>   treated  as  an  assignment  of text  to  the  variable  var, 
>   performed  at  the  time  when  that  argument would  be accessed as a
>   file.**

In Gawk, I saw that variable assignments are specified after option `-v`. I was wondering if what is described in the quote without option `-v` still works with Gawk?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The variable will not be available in the `BEGIN` block since the assignment happens "at the time when that argument would be accessed as a file", but that's the same as for all other `awk` implementations.

```
$ echo 'input data' | gawk -vvar1="hello" 'BEGIN { print var1, var2 } { print $0, var1, var2 }' var2='world!'
hello
input data hello world!
```

Comment: Thanks. Since the assignment  `var2='world!'` happens "at the time when that argument would be accessed as a file", and there is no file named `var2='world!'`, why does `print $0, var1, var2`  print `world!` for `var2`?

Comment: @Tim because since there is no file with that name and since it has the form of a variable assignment, the `awk` variable `var2` is given the value `hello!`.

Comment: Then is it true that awk doesn't interpret every non-option argument as an input filename? There are two ways to assign variables, with `-v` option or without, which happen at different times.

Comment: @Tim To clarify and correct my previous comment (which was partly wrong): If there is a string on the command line that looks like an `awk` variable assignment, then that assignment is carried out after the `BEGIN` block, even if there is a file with that as a filename. If there is a file with that as a filename, it will be ignored and not used as an input file.

Comment: @Tim All this is easy to test.

Comment: @Tim And yes, there are two ways of handing over variables and their values to `awk` from outside the script itself. Variables defined with `-v` are available in `BEGIN`.

Comment: Thanks. Is `-v` an extension of gawk, and did it not exist in awk when The AWK Programming Language was written?

Comment: @Tim The `-v` option [is specified in the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/awk.html). It is however not mentioned in the 1988 edition of the AWK book (it should have been mentioned on page 63 if it had been implemented at that time). It must have been a later invention. All modern implementations of `awk` (`gawk`, `mawk` and `nawk` (BSD `awk`)) has `-v`.

Comment: The gawk manual has a lot of history information. -v was added in SVR4 ('89). Note that some implementations, you need `-v var=value`, not `-vvar=value`